# QT Webkit HTML5 support errors

Tags: html, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I am a new user of QT. I just created a simple Web View and I opened: http://html5test.com/ and it shows:

> YOUR BROWSER SCORES 392 OUT OF 555 POINTS

When I open in Chrome, it shows:

> YOUR BROWSER SCORES 521 OUT OF 555 POINTS

What can I do to solve this problem in QT Webkit web view?

For example, one visible problem is that I cannot make fullscreen on video players.

Thank you!

I am using linux mint 12 kde as my OS.

Comment: You might want to try [QWebEngineView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) from Qt5, it is based on Chromium as a backend and is said to be much more HTML5 compliant than QtWebKit.

Comment: "What can I do to solve this problem in QT Webkit web view?" Don't use it :)